# Sqlite proper commit for possible crashing method

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

*Python 3.5. Sqlite3*

The goal is to have a method that add records to a log table but it doesn't knows whether that method will crash:

1. open logger connection
2. logger insert "Method starts"
3. do something
4. logger insert "I did something"
5. do another thing
6. logger insert "I did another thing"
7. logger insert "Method ends"
8. close logger connection

**How do I commit that?**

Until now while learning Sqlite I though I had to use as many `execute`as I wanted and just commit them before closing the connection to actually "save" the changes, something like this:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("myfile.db")
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO foo VALUES (?,?)", (var1, var2))
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO other VALUES (?,?)", (var1, var2))
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO another VALUES (?,?)", (var1, var2))
conexion.commit() # Save all
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```

But if we take into account that it can crash **before** it gets to the commit part, how would you do? why?

For reference, this is my real code:

```
def connect(database):
    """Open a connection and a cursor to the database file provided."""
    conexion = sqlite3.connect(database + ".db")
    cursor = conexion.cursor()
    return (conexion, cursor)

def disconnect(conexion, cursor, savechanges=False):
    """Disconnect from database, closing the cursor first.
    Save the cursor data with a commit if specified.
    """
    cursor.close()
    if savechanges:
        conexion.commit()
    conexion.close()

def logger_query(cursor, comments):
    """It inserts into the log database an unique record with comments"""
    record_date = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Log VALUES (?,?)", (comments, record_date))
```

Called as this:

```
conexionlog, cursorlog = connect("Log")
logger_query(cursorlog, "Record starts")
#... Do something
logger_query(cursorlog, "Record something")
#... Do another something
logger_query(cursorlog, "Record another something")
#... Maybe I crash here...
logger_query(cursorlog, "Record ends")
disconnect(conexionlog, cursorlog, True)
```

Comment: Umm... why not catch such an exception and do a commit in the `except` block?

Comment: See my comment to @Amber. An exception wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Updated based on comment clarifications:

Per your comment, you don't mean an exception, but an actual hard termination (e.g. power failure). In that case, you need to commit your log queries individually, as a committed transaction is the only thing that's going to be persisted through a hard termination like that.

```
def logger_query(cursor, comments):
    """It inserts into the log database an unique record with comments"""
    record_date = str(datetime.datetime.now())
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Log VALUES (?,?)", (comments, record_date))
    cursor.connection.commit()
```

---

#### Previous answer:

Assuming by `crash` you mean an exception gets raised, you can use a [`try`/`finally`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions) block:

```
conexionlog, cursorlog = connect("Log")
try:
    logger_query(cursorlog, "Record starts")
    #... Do something
    logger_query(cursorlog, "Record something")
    #... Do another something
    logger_query(cursorlog, "Record another something")
    #... Maybe I crash here...
    logger_query(cursorlog, "Record ends")
finally:
    disconnect(conexionlog, cursorlog, True)
```

The code in the `finally` block will be run even if the code in the `try` block raises an exception. Note however that only the code from the `try` block that has already run by the point of the exception will be run; the rest of the `try` block will not be run (execution will move directly to the `finally` block, followed by the exception continuing to raise up the stack).

Comment: Hm maybe I wasn't clear with the crash. Let's put an stupid example: Someone unplugs the power wire from the computer. In that example, the script never gets to execute the `finally` part of your code either, but you would want to know what is the "last" saved records. That is my goal. So I would want to know how to properly save each individual record while keeping the connection and the cursor opened.

Comment: In that case, you need to commit after every single log write you do. You can't hold off on committing while also protecting yourself against power-outage style crashes.

Comment: So I can add a `conn.commit()` line at the `logger_query` method and nothing bad would happen? I though I could only commit once before closing the connection O,o (total newbie fail).

Comment: You can commit as many times per connection as you want. (https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.commit)

Comment: As per your last edit, You read my mind. Thank you for clarification :D